# How to import private network repository into Azure Devops

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, web-services, azure-devops, devops

I have a gitlab was called URL *https://gitlab.organization-name.com/* that is a my **private network** for internal access only. And I have a Azure DevOps account, I wanna import my private network repo in *https://gitlab.organization-name.com/username/test-ci-cd.git* to my Azure account. Does is it possible for importing? And, How should I do?

*Note: for **public network** repo like *https://gitlab.com/username/test-ci-cd.git*, It is work fine.

Comment: Did you try already wth Basic Authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-a-new-repo

Comment: Why can't you do a mirror clone to a local computer, add a new remote, and then push it to Azure DevOps?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, I have already try, It is not work.

Comment: @DanielMann, I can not do that, because my organization is not allow to store source in public network.

Comment: Azure DevOps is a "public network" (i.e. a cloud-hosted service). So if you can't put your code into Azure DevOps because it's a cloud-hosted service, then what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I contact to support Azure DevOps Enginner Team. He siad "I can not do that Unless I changed my private to public network"